# Align Image to Top Right, But Not Before Text on Mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, image, alignment, media

In the wordpress text editor, is there any good way to align an image to the top right of an opening paragraph when on a desktop, but **below** the opening paragraph when on mobile.

Currently, I insert the image before the text and align it to the right (which works great on desktop), but when on mobile, the image is displayed **before** the text.

I'm comfortable with how to make the image responsive when on mobile. I just don't know how to maintain the flow of the content when reading from left to right.

Thanks,
Andy.

Comment: Create [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)